# Flask Tacacs+ authentication

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I've written a flask app which has been working fine with its own authentication on a MySQL Database but I'm now being asked to authenticate against a TACACS+ box instead of the internal authentication.

I've searched for python tacacs modules and have only found servers, there certainly doesn't appear to be a flask module for tacacs. Typically i fould perl ones but I don't feel that writing a wrapper around perl to get the authentication is a neat solution.

I could write something to pass through the auth via SSH I guess, and if the auth works on a device then the user is "OK" but that seems like a really horrible way to do it.

Does anyone know how to get python to authenticate against a TACACS+ box? When I've looked for how TACACS works on the internet the results seem very scant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using https://github.com/ansible/tacacs_plus .
from the site.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import tacacs_plus
    auth = tacacs_plus.TACACSClient('host', 49, 'secret',timeout=10).authenticate(
'username', 'password', tacacs_plus.TAC_PLUS_AUTHEN_TYPE_ASCII
    )
    print "PASS!" if auth.valid else "FAIL!"
```

Comment: Thanks Allan. That looks great! I used a workround as this question was a while back, but I may reimplement with this now I know it exists.